# XSLT to remove all but one complex element

Tags: xslt

I have a large XML (from Agile) that I need to pass into a system that cannot quickly read large XMLs.  There is a repeating element that has a unique child element, I'd like to remove all of the others except the one I pass in with a parameter.

```
<AgileData xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2013/09/">
    <Parts uniqueId="10000:6049719:8336339">
        <TitleBlock><Number>300901</Number></TitleBlock>
        <PartType>Raw Material</PartType>
        <LifecyclePhase>Production</LifecyclePhase>
        <Description>Prod 1 Desc</Description>
        <ProductLines><Value>123-Line</Value></ProductLines>
    </Parts>
    <Parts uniqueId="10000:6049719:8337000">
        <TitleBlock><Number>300902</Number></TitleBlock>
        <PartType>Raw Material</PartType>
        <LifecyclePhase>Prototype</LifecyclePhase>
        <Description>Prod 2 Desc</Description>
        <ProductLines><Value>222-Line</Value></ProductLines>
    </Parts>
    <Parts uniqueId="10000:6049719:8337034">
        <TitleBlock><Number>300908</Number></TitleBlock>
        <PartType>Raw Material</PartType>
        <LifecyclePhase>Prototype</LifecyclePhase>
        <Description>Prod 3 Desc</Description>
        <ProductLines><Value>123-Line</Value></ProductLines>
    </Parts>
</AgileData>
```

Desired Output is the following when passing in the parameter Item

```
<AgileData xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2013/09/">
    <Parts uniqueId="10000:6049719:8337000">
        <TitleBlock><Number>300902</Number></TitleBlock>
        <PartType>Raw Material</PartType>
        <LifecyclePhase>Prototype</LifecyclePhase>
        <Description>Prod 2 Desc</Description>
        <ProductLines><Value>222-Line</Value></ProductLines>
    </Parts>
</AgileData>
```

This what I have so far, though it's not working.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2013/09/">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="Item" select="300902" />

    <xsl:template match="/AgileData">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Parts"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//Parts/*[TitleBlock/Number='$Item']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After its working I'll change the parameter to just have a name and not a hardcoded value as it will get passed in from the engine.  I can use XSLT 1.0 and 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2013/09/">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pItem" select="300902" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="x:Parts[x:TitleBlock/x:Number/number() ne $pItem]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<AgileData xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2013/09/">
    <Parts uniqueId="10000:6049719:8336339">
        <TitleBlock><Number>300901</Number></TitleBlock>
        <PartType>Raw Material</PartType>
        <LifecyclePhase>Production</LifecyclePhase>
        <Description>Prod 1 Desc</Description>
        <ProductLines><Value>123-Line</Value></ProductLines>
    </Parts>
    <Parts uniqueId="10000:6049719:8337000">
        <TitleBlock><Number>300902</Number></TitleBlock>
        <PartType>Raw Material</PartType>
        <LifecyclePhase>Prototype</LifecyclePhase>
        <Description>Prod 2 Desc</Description>
        <ProductLines><Value>222-Line</Value></ProductLines>
    </Parts>
    <Parts uniqueId="10000:6049719:8337034">
        <TitleBlock><Number>300908</Number></TitleBlock>
        <PartType>Raw Material</PartType>
        <LifecyclePhase>Prototype</LifecyclePhase>
        <Description>Prod 3 Desc</Description>
        <ProductLines><Value>123-Line</Value></ProductLines>
    </Parts>
</AgileData>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<AgileData xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2013/09/">

    <Parts uniqueId="10000:6049719:8337000">
        <TitleBlock><Number>300902</Number></TitleBlock>
        <PartType>Raw Material</PartType>
        <LifecyclePhase>Prototype</LifecyclePhase>
        <Description>Prod 2 Desc</Description>
        <ProductLines><Value>222-Line</Value></ProductLines>
    </Parts>

</AgileData>
```

---

**XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2013/09/">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pItem" select="300902" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="x:Parts">
    <xsl:if 
        test="x:TitleBlock/x:Number = $pItem"><xsl:call-template name="identity"/></xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct / wanted result is produced.

**Do note**:

1. The use and overriding of the **[identity rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying)**
2. The use of the same namespace as the **[default namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#dt-defaultNS)** in the XML document.

To learn more about the either of these important concepts, do search SO or the internet for "**[`XSLT identity template / rule`](https://www.google.com/search?q=XSLT%20identity%20template%20%2F%20rule&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS826US826&oq=XSLT%20identity%20template%20%2F%20rule&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.631j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**" and "**[`XSLT processing a document in default namespace`](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS826US826&sxsrf=ACYBGNTxhGp8C31wMkG1o89z9VdrD3Vz1w%3A1578018061827&ei=DaUOXuCUMpH09APd4IqIDA&q=XSLT+processing+a+document+in+default+namespace&oq=XSLT+processing+a+document+in+default+namespace&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160.79861.79861..81891...0.1..0.80.80.1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.......0i71.hzu7Qazm9J8&ved=0ahUKEwigz5iwr-bmAhUROn0KHV2wAsEQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)**"

**See also**:

1. Dave Pawson's [XSLT FAQ on Identity transformation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310094720/http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)
2. Dave Pawson's [XSLT FAQ on Namespaces](https://web.archive.org/web/20180326184423/http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N5536.html)

Answer (score 1):

Or simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2013/09/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="Item" select="300902" />

<xsl:template match="/ns0:AgileData">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ns0:Parts[ns0:TitleBlock/ns0:Number=$Item]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you can use **XSLT 2.0,** it can be even simpler:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/xml/plm/2013/09/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="Item" select="300902" />

<xsl:template match="/AgileData">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Parts[TitleBlock/Number=$Item]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```